# Add TEXT to Title only IF condition is met

Tags: php, conditional-statements

Hi I trying to improve my Titles by creating automatic SEO friendly Titles based on Product Name, Price & Category which I am acheiving like this:

```
$catName = isset($category_info) ? " - ".$category_info['name'] : "";
            $titlePrice = $this->data['special'] ? $this->data['special'] : ($this->data['price'] ? $this->data['price'] : ($this->data['tax'] ? $this->data['tax'] : ""));
$newTitle = $product_info['name']." - ".$titlePrice.$catName." - ".$this->config->get('config_title');
            $this->document->setTitle($newTitle);
```

However I'd ideally like to include the text 'SALE' **if** 'special' (sale prices) are smaller than 'price' (normal price) - ie if there IS a value for 'special' price.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Somebody's got a bad case of *ternaryitis*.

Comment: OK - sorry about that - 1st post apologies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood what you need you can simply add the `SALE` text when `special` price is set:

```
$catName = isset($category_info) ? " - ".$category_info['name'] : "";
$tax = $this->data['tax'] ? $this->data['tax'] : "";
$price = $this->data['price'] ? $this->data['price'] : $tax;
$titlePrice = $this->data['special'] ? $this->data['special']." SALE" : $price;
$newTitle = $product_info['name']." - ". $titlePrice . $catName. " - ".$this->config->get('config_title');
```

I've splitted it for the sake of readability (*just too many ternary operators!*) and added `." SALE"` at the 4th row.

---

If you don't want to write `SALE` right after the price you can simply add

```
$sale = $this->data['special'] ? "SALE" : "";
```

and append `$sale` wherever you want.

Comment: Brilliant thanks @Guglie - I am very grateful, particularly for your comment about appending as I realise the flexibility will be very helpful. For Now I have this working very nicely:

Comment: Sorry - don't know how to split but here goes:`code in backticks` $catName = isset($category_info) ? " - ".$category_info['name'] : "";
   $titlePrice = $this->data['special'] ? $this->data['special'] : ($this->data['price'] ? $this->data['price'] : ($this->data['tax'] ? $this->data['tax'] : ""));
   $sale = $this->data['special'] ? "ON SALE! - " : "";
$newTitle = $sale.$product_info['name']." - ".$titlePrice.$catName." - ".$this->config->get('config_title');
   $this->document->setTitle($newTitle);

Comment: @user2159775 fine, but try not to put too much code in comments... by the way: you're welcome! Can you mark the answer as accepted?